# How to call a gRPC function which return empty

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

Here is the defination of the function at the file ns.pb.go

```
CreateMACCommandQueueItem(ctx context.Context, in *CreateMACCommandQueueItemRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*empty.Empty, error)
```

Here is the part of main.go code that I write:

```golang
resp, err := serviceClient.CreateMACCommandQueueItem(context.Background(), &ns.CreateMACCommandQueueItemRequest{
    DevEui:     devEUI[:],
    Cid:        uint32(lorawan.LinkADRReq),
    Commands:   [][]byte{b},
})

if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("The MACCommand has been enqueued")
```

Here is the error:

```
.\main.go:62:2: resp declared but not used
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this:

```
if _, err := serviceClient.CreateMACCommandQueueItem(context.Background(), &ns.CreateMACCommandQueueItemRequest{
    DevEui:     devEUI[:],
    Cid:        uint32(lorawan.LinkADRReq),
    Commands:   [][]byte{b},

}): err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Some adjustments have been made to the program structure, which is really novel.